# How do I return to the main page that my GUI loads to using a button,

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.8

I am new to python/tkinter and I created a GUI, The app(GUI) is a beer app that shows you descriptions of beer types and has a random beer selector if you cant decide what to drink. my problem is when I run the app, it opens to the main screen (the first thing you see when the GUI opens) that has 11 buttons at the top of the screen in a frame and a frame in the middle of the screen that says "welcome to the app" each button works as I wanted (when one of the buttons is pressed, the frame that is in the middle of the screen disappears and a new frame shows up with the text I set and a picture next to it) but once I click any of the buttons and the main screen is gone, I am able to get the main screen to come back by using a button and linking it to a def that uses the .lift() but the frame and picture from clicking one of the other buttons stays on the screen and I cant figure out how to get them to disappear. I also cant get my random beer selector to show up on any screen besides the main screen, I tried a bunch of different things but in the end I put it on the from since it wont work anywhere else.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

'''

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
import random
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 1200
BLUE = '#146F80'
GRAY = '#4A4A4A'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Welcome to the beer app!")


def beer(event):
    image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\john\Pictures\PNG\american pale ale.png")

    canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=400, bg=BLUE, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    item4 = canvas2.create_image(225, 210, image=photo)

    canvas2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.25, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.5)

    desc_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=GRAY)
    desc_frame.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.58)

    beer_desc = tk.Label(desc_frame, text="Beer description here", wraplength=680, justify=LEFT, font=('Gadugi', 18), bg=GRAY,
                         fg='white')
    beer_desc.pack()

    item4.pack()


def randbeer(event):
    beer_list = ["Stout", "Sour Beer", "American Brown Ale", "American Brown Ale", "Porter", "Indian Pale Ale",
                 "Wheat Beer", "Amber Ale", "English Pale Ale", "Pilsner", "Lager"]
    beer_item = random.choice(beer_list)
    updatedisplay(beer_item)


def updatedisplay(event):
    displayVariable.set(event)


def menu(event):
    button12.master.lift()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, bg=BLUE, highlightbackground=GRAY)
Canvas.pack(canvas)

welcome_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=GRAY)
welcome_frame.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.3, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.6)

button_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=GRAY)
button_frame.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=0.1, relwidth=1.0)

random_beer_frame = tk.Frame(welcome_frame, bg="gray")
random_beer_frame.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.75, relheight=0.097, relwidth=0.35)

button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="American Pale Ale")
button.config(bg="#5C665B", fg="black", font=("AR JULIAN", 9))
button.bind("<Button-1>", beer)
button.place(relx=0.005, rely=0.2, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.1)

button12 = tk.Button(welcome_frame, text="Random beer")
button12.config(bg="#5C665B", fg="black", font=("AR JULIAN", 12))
button12.bind("<Button-1>", randbeer)
button12.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.75, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.15)
displayVariable = StringVar()
displayLabel = Label(random_beer_frame, textvariable=displayVariable, bg="gray", font=("AR JULIAN", 18))
displayLabel.pack()

button13 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Main Menu")
button13.config(bg="#5C665B", fg="black", font=("AR JULIAN", 9))
button13.bind("<Button-1>", menu)
button13.place(relx=0.918, rely=0.2, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.06)

welcome_text = "\nWelcome to the beer app!"

welcome_text = tk.Label(welcome_frame, text=welcome_text, font=("Gadui", 24), bg=GRAY, fg="white")
welcome_text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. First make all the main display elements in `beer()` `global`, so you can reference them elsewhere.

```
def beer(event):
    image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\john\Pictures\PNG\american pale ale.png")

    global canvas2
    canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=400, bg=BLUE, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    
    item4 = canvas2.create_image(225, 210, image=photo)
    
    canvas2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.25, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.5)

    global desc_frame
    desc_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=GRAY)
    desc_frame.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.58)

    global beer_desc
    beer_desc = tk.Label(desc_frame, text="Beer description here", wraplength=680, justify=LEFT, font=('Gadugi', 18), bg=GRAY,
                         fg='white')
    beer_desc.pack()

    item4.pack()
```

Then `GRIDMANAGER_forget()` them in `menu()`.

```
def menu(event):
    beer_desc.pack_forget()
    canvas2.pack_forget()
    desc_frame.place_forget()
    button12.master.lift()
```

This will fix your immediate problem, but in all honesty the way you are designing this app is very bad. You are referring to major elements via the `master` of `Buttons` and other such confusing things. I would highly recommend considering a more modular approach. Make a `Frame`. Consider it a page. Put everything for that page in that frame. Give the frame a meaningful name. Repeat this for all of your "pages". Once you do that, you can easily have buttons hide/show entire frames (pages). Imagine if every book was one page long and in order to read the next page you had to first erase the current page and completely rewrite the next page from scratch. This is what you are doing. Just build all your pages and make `Buttons` "flip" to the already complete desired page, **as a whole**.

---

I refactored your entire app as an example of my prior statement. It still isn't amazing, but it's substantially better than what you currently have.

```
import tkinter as tk, random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 1200
BLUE = '#146F80'
GRAY = '#4A4A4A'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Welcome to the beer app!")
root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+300+150')

#make the menu occupy all available width
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#make the main display container occupy all available height
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

def change_page(name):
    global pages, current
    if current:
       current.place_forget()
       
    current = pages[name][0]
    current.place(**pages[name][1])
   
def menu():
    bar = tk.Frame(root, bg=GRAY)
    bar.grid(sticky='we')
    bar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    opts = dict(bg="#5C665B", fg="black", font=("AR JULIAN", 9), activebackground="#5C665B")
    pads = dict(padx=16, pady=16, ipadx=6, ipady=6)
    
    apa_btn = tk.Button(bar, text="American Pale Ale", **opts)
    apa_btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:change_page('description'))
    apa_btn.grid(sticky='w', **pads)
    
    menu_btn = tk.Button(bar, text="Main Menu", **opts)
    menu_btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:change_page('main'))
    menu_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e', **pads)
    
def main(master):
    main_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg=GRAY)
    
    welcome_msg = "\nWelcome to the beer app!"
    welcome_lbl = tk.Label(main_frame, text=welcome_msg, font=("Gadui", 24), bg=GRAY, fg="white")
    welcome_lbl.pack()
    
    random_beer_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg="gray")
    random_beer_frame.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.75, relheight=0.097, relwidth=0.35)

    def randbeer(event):
        beerlist = ["Stout", "Sour Beer", "American Brown Ale", "American Brown Ale", "Porter", "Indian Pale Ale",
                    "Wheat Beer", "Amber Ale", "English Pale Ale", "Pilsner", "Lager"]
        random_beer_lbl['text'] = random.choice(beerlist)
                     
    random_btn = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Random beer")
    random_btn.config(bg="#5C665B", fg="black", font=("AR JULIAN", 12))
    random_btn.bind("<Button-1>", randbeer)
    random_btn.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.75, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.15)
    
    random_beer_lbl = tk.Label(random_beer_frame, bg="gray", font=("AR JULIAN", 18))
    random_beer_lbl.pack()
    
    return main_frame
    
def description(master):
    global images
    main_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg=BLUE)
    
    #I don't have your image so this was commented out for testing
    #image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\john\Pictures\PNG\american pale ale.png")
    #images['apa'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, name='apa')
    #tk.Label(main_frame, image='apa', bg=BLUE).place(relx=0.0, rely=0.25, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.5)
    
    desc_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=GRAY)
    desc_frame.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.58)

    beer_desc_lbl = tk.Label(desc_frame, text="Beer description here", wraplength=680, justify=tk.LEFT, font=('Gadugi', 18), bg=GRAY,fg='white')
    beer_desc_lbl.pack()
    
    return main_frame

#init menu
menu()  

#this serves as the master for all content
display = tk.Frame(root, bg=BLUE)
display.grid(sticky='nswe')  

#used to keep image references alive
images = dict()

#a reference to every page and it's placement
pages = dict(
    main        = (main(display), dict(relx=0.2, rely=0.3, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.6)),
    description = (description(display), dict(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1))
)

#a reference to the current page
current = None

#init main page
change_page('main')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! and good to know, I will try and make them pages instead, I just started learning python a few weeks ago so I am still learning, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Madhatter Please consider accepting my answer (click the big checkmark to the left of my answer) if it solved your problems. I already made them pages for you, see the end of my answer.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to add my image back into the page and when I uncomment those lines it gives me this error: line 101, in <module>
    description=(description(display), dict(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1))
 line 78, in description images['apa'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, name='apa')
NameError: name 'images' is not defined

Comment: @Madhatter - woops. I see my mistake. Simply move `images=dict()` up a few lines so it is before `pages=dict(...)`. Sorry about that. I edited my answer to include the change. The problem is that `description` was being called before `images` was created.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for all the questions about it, but for the buttons, I am trying to add more buttons next to "American Pale Ale" so that they are in a row next to each other, when I add a new button i'm having a hard time placing it where I want, in this code can I only use 'nswe' to place it? i tried using 'row= #a number, column= #a number' I tried using padx and pady also. For the picture I was able to get it back by moving that code above description but its cutting off the top of the image, is there an adjustment so it shows the whole picture

Comment: comment out `bar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`. Then add more buttons by incrementing the column number, for each button. `apa_btn` does not state row and column because it is the equivalent of saying `row=0` and `column=0`. As far as the picture question goes you need to ask a new SO question to get that answer. That's not an issue with my code. That's an issue actually with your code ~ something I didn't change, at all. However, `relheight` might be a good place to start.

Comment: relheight fixed it and the buttons are now in a row, thanks

Comment: @Madhatter ~ ;). I misspoke about one thing. I claimed that `grid()` is the equivalent of `column=0` and `row=0`. That is only true if all of your rows and columns are completely empty. It is actually the equivalent of `column=0` and `next available row`. Since that button was the first thing I stuck in it's master `next available row` was `0`. Note that `next available row` means in total. So, let's assume column0 ended at row4 and column1 ended at row8 ~ `grid()` would produce `column=0, row=9`. This is because column0 doesn't really end at row4, that may just be the last one you used.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I was able to get them all in the places i needed them to be and finished the app. It works like I was intending it to, I will definitely be using pages instead of how I was doing it before from now on.

Comment: @Madhatter ~ come up with a better page system. The system I gave you isn't terrible, but there is plenty of room for improvement. I was trying to build a page system based on your existing gui so it would have as little as possible for you to familiarize yourself with. However, using `place` for everything is a bad design choice, especially when you are basing everything on relative sizes. If I were you, I would spend some time building a reusable page system that is really solid, and then use it to build an app ~ many apps.